# jQuery add a link to remove a control dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can generate the controls but can't remove them. I'm trying to add a 'Link' which will call a function to remove dynamically created control. The control and link are next to each other. Here's the Java script and mark-up to create the control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() { // when document has loaded

            //   <input id="File1" type="file" runat="server" size="60" />

            var i = $('input').size() + 1; // check how many input exists on the document and add 1 for the add command to work


            $('a#add').click(function() { // when you click the add link
                $('<p><input type="file" id="' + i + '" name="' + 'dynamic:' + i + '" /> <a href="#" id="' + 're' + i + ' " onclick="removeControl("' + '\'#' + i + '\''+ '")">+</a></p>').appendTo('body'); // append (add) a new input to the document.

                // if you have the input inside a form, change body to form in the appendTo
                i++; //after the click i will be i = 3 if you click again i will be i = 4s
            });

            function removeControl(controlId) {

                $(controlId).remove();
            }


        }); </script>


   <div>
        <a href="#" id="add">Add</a>

<br />


<p><input type="file" id="1" /></p>

    </div>
```

The script to create the Link to remove the control is not working. The onClick attribute is not mark-up correctly when I use Firebug to see the source.

```
<a href="#" id="' + 're' + i + ' " onclick="removeControl("' + '\'#' + i + '\''+ '")">+</a>
```

I just wanna add a Link to remove the generated control and the link itself.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to remove the `<input>` or the entire `<p>` you added?  One more thing, IDs can't start with a number, you need to prefix it with something, e.g. `"file1"`, etc.

Comment: I want to remove <input> and <a> that I added. Yes, by removing <p> will remove both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove an element from the Dom which was included via javascript you need to  [attach or rebind an event handler](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F).

```
$('a.remove').live('click', function() {
  // Stuff to remove
});
```

### Working solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       
        // Init counter
        var counter = 0;
        
        // Add Elements
        $('#add').click(function() {

            counter++ // Increment counter

            var add_input = '<p><input type="file" />';
            var add_link = '<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>';

            // Append Elements if counter smaller 4
            if (counter <= 4) {
                $('body').append('<p>' + add_input + add_link + '</p>');
            }
            return counter;
         });

         // Remove Elements
         $('.remove').live('click', function() {
             counter--; // Decrement counter
             $(this).parent('p').remove();
         });
     });
</script>

<a href="#" id="add">Add</a>
```

FYI-> Always reduce dom inserts to a minimum.

Comment: How can I allow only 4 controls to be added only?

Comment: See edit above. If you need to add more then 4 controls just change the value within the if statement to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your removeControl function to this:

```
function removeControl(driver) {
  $(driver).closest("p").remove();
}
```

Then, change the call to the function in your anchor to this:

```
onclick="removeControl(this);return false;"
```

Should be good to go...